# What does 'extract exception, please check files' mean?

Tags: files, system-error, zip

I've been trying to open a `.zip` file on my Android device, and whenever I try it tells me the same thing over and over again:

> Extract exception, please check files

What does this mean?

I went through all my files, and then when I try to extract the `.zip` file again, it gives me an empty folder and says that same message.

Can someone please help? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check if you can extract the zip archive on a PC? Maybe it's just a damaged archive....

Comment: As @Flow mentioned, did you try to extract files on a PC? Besides, what app / tool are you using to extract? What do you mean by "go through" all files? Still my guess is the ZIP file may be corrupt.

Comment: Also be sure that its a zip file not a `rar` or `tar`. Also use ES Explorer or File Expert program to open the file.

Comment: It means the author of the app you're using needs to hire someone who can write error messages.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely explanation is that the compressed file is corrupt. Are you trying to uncompress a rar file, or a standard zip file? rar extraction is only supported with certain processors.

The easiest way to tell, is to try and extract *the same* zip file on a computer, and see what it says.